# Show that a biholomorphic map f is conformal

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, inverse-function, conformal-geometry

Let $f: D \to D'$ be biholomorphic map between two domains $\mathit{D}$ and $\mathit{D'}$. By considering the equation $f(f^{-1}(w)) = w$ (for $w \in \mathit{D'}$) show that $f$ is conformal.

My attempt:
By the definition of biholomorphism, both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are holomorphic so that condition is satisfied but I am not sure how to use the given equation to show that the derivative of $f$ is always non-zero.

Comment: What is your definition of “conformal”?

Comment: try computing the same thing two different ways: i.e. derivative of the identity map and also use the chain rule compute the derivative of $f\circ f^{-1}$

Comment: @MartinR holomorphic and non zero derivative implies conformal

Answer (score 0):

This answer expands @user8675309 's comment:

For all $z\in D$, let $w=f(z)$, then $z=f^{-1}(w)$,
\begin{align}
1=\frac{d}{dw}w=\frac{d}{dw}f(z)=\frac{d}{dw}[f(f^{-1}(w))]\require{extpfeil}\xlongequal{\text{chain rule}}f'(f^{-1}(w))\cdot\frac{d}{dw}[f^{-1}(w)]\\
\implies f'(f^{-1}(w))\ne0\\
\implies f'(z)\ne0
\end{align}
so $f'\ne0$ on $D$.

so $f$ is conformal.